# Multiple Object Mapper Resolvers

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger

Our app accepts JSON payloads via Swagger model, and it works fine 99% of the time.

However, as time goes by it was noticed that sometimes it fails to parse requests because of unknown properties. Fine, then we wrote a short object mapper resolver with `Priority (-.....)` and started the debugger.

It seems that neither JSON from Swagger nor our hand crafted object mapper resolver are invoked during a call, and the reader actually comes from `Jackson-databind` jar.

Couple of questions:
1. How come `Priority` does not take affect in this case?
2. How can we force it to use our handcrafted resolver?

Object Mapper Resolver:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
public class ObjectMapperResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>{
```

Comment: What's your jackson version?

Comment: @user7294900 2.96

Comment: There's a similar issue that should be fixed in 2.96 https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/issues/86

Comment: @user7294900 thank you for the reference. We are using 2.96 and are seeing this issue.

Comment: Maybe add a comment with your details

Comment: @user7294900 what else would you like to know?